# Table-less designs to present non-tabluar data in a tabular-like style worth it?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a key,value list containing 6 keys and 6 values.  I wish to render these key, value pairs in HTML in a tabular-like fashion (presentation), though they are not necessarily tabular data.  So the HTML `<table>` tag is not recommended for two reasons:

1. There should be a separation of presentation from data.
2. The `<table>` tag should not be used for presentational purposes, only for tabular data.

Anyways, the basic idea is to present these values very simply such as the following:

[image]

This is very easily achieved with HTML/CSS and the `<table>` tag.  Sample code is provided:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Test 1</title>   
    <style type="text/css">

    table {
        width: 300px;
        border: solid 1px black;
        text-align: center;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<table>
    <tr><td>Key 1</td><td>Val 1</td><td>Key 4</td><td>Val 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Key 2</td><td>Val 2</td><td>Key 5</td><td>Val 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Key 3</td><td>Val 3</td><td>Key 6</td><td>Val 6</td></tr>   
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Moreover, when the *ZOOM*, a common feature in many browsers, is set higher, all rows remain intact as the user would intuitively expect:
[image]

A common *table-less* design for such a structure is through the CSS `float` style and a combination of `<ul>` and `<li>` elements.

Sample code is given for this approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Test 1</title>   
    <style type="text/css">
    .table {
        width: 300px;
        border: solid 1px black;
    }

    .table ul {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;   
        padding-left: 0px;  
    }

    .table ul li {
        width: 75px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;       
    }

    .clear {
        clear: both;    
    }

    /* For modern browsers */
    .cf:before,
    .cf:after {
        content:"";
        display:table;
    }

    .cf:after {
        clear:both;
    }

    /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
    .cf {
        zoom:1;
    }


    </style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="table cf">
    <ul>
        <li>Key 1</li>
        <li>Key 2</li>
        <li>Key 3</li>
    </ul>   

    <ul>
        <li>Val 1</li>
        <li>Val 2</li>
        <li>Val 3</li>
    </ul>   

    <ul>
        <li>Key 4</li>
        <li>Key 5</li>
        <li>Key 6</li>
    </ul>   

    <ul>
        <li>Val 4</li>
        <li>Val 5</li>
        <li>Val 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

It works as prescribed, and in current browsers the *ZOOM* works, too.  (Unless in IE6, the text zooming pushes everything around, it's a mess).

There are a number of things that make it unintuitive to me:

1. More CSS is required, especially for the clearfix
2. Ideally for accessibility you would want each Key to be presented in order followed by each Value, here you get 3 keys, 3 values, 3 keys, 3 values.  Which makes rendering this option without CSS look pretty strange, whereas the table one without CSS still makes sense.

So basically, the question boils down to: since tables play so well presenting information in a tabular style why try to use `<ul>` and complicated floats and other CSS trickery to mimic the same style when presenting non-tabular data in a tabular-like fashion?  What exactly is the major benefit here from striving to rid `<table>` from all HTML?

**EDIT**
I know this is getting a bit off the original question, several answers suggested the use of `<dl>` to make it more semantically accurate.  I agree.  So example code for that approach follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Test 1</title>   
    <style type="text/css">
    .table {
        width: 300px;
        border: solid 1px black;
    }

    .table dl {
        float: left;
        padding-left: 0px;  
        width: 150px;
    }

    .table dl dt, .table dl dd {
        width: 75px;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    /* clear fix is below */
    /* For modern browsers */
    .cf:before,
    .cf:after {
        content:"";
        display:table;
    }

    .cf:after {
        clear:both;
    }

    /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
    .cf {
        zoom:1;
    }


    </style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="table cf">
  <dl>
    <dt>Key1</dt>
    <dd>Value1</dd>
    <dt>Key2</dt>
    <dd>Value2</dd>
    <dt>Key3</dt>
    <dd>Value3</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt>Key4</dt>
    <dd>Value4</dd>
    <dt>Key5</dt>
    <dd>Value5</dd>
    <dt>Key6</dt>
    <dd>Value6</dd>
  </dl>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

This still gets the same visual effect:

[image]

However, what is bothersome is that in order to achieve this two separate definition lists are created.  When in reality, it is suppose to just be one list:

```
  <dl>
    <dt>Key1</dt>
    <dd>Value1</dd>
    <dt>Key2</dt>
    <dd>Value2</dd>
    <dt>Key3</dt>
    <dd>Value3</dd>
    <dt>Key4</dt>
    <dd>Value4</dd>
    <dt>Key5</dt>
    <dd>Value5</dd>
    <dt>Key6</dt>
    <dd>Value6</dd>
  </dl>
```

The only reason to include the split was for presentational purposes.  How would you get around this one?

Comment: You dont need that clearing div, there are other ways to clear floats. Take a look at the `.clearfix` class in many css frameworks like 960.gs and Blueprint-css.

Comment: I updated the example to use a clearfix method instead.

Comment: About styling a single `dl`: [CSS3 has a solution for this here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol): column-count. In principal, styling can be as simple as `dl { column-count:2; } dt, dd { float:left; width:50%; margin:0; }`. This shows that the designers of CSS3 understand the use case. However, if you try this, you'll find it doesn't work. It can be made to work in modern Firefox and Chrome by adding `-moz-` and `-webkit-` respectively in front of `column-count` but other browsers are not yet so accommodating...

Comment: ... It's at this point that you need to compromise just enough in your markup to compensate for the fact that the state of the art in presentation is not where we'd like it to be, and in this case that means using two lists. There's a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/YKsKG/1/) showing how it's supposed to work if you view it in Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a prime example of where you should use a `<dl>` tag. It's like `<ul>` but allows key,value pairs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/dl

For example:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Key 1</dt>
    <dd>Value 1</dd>
    <dt>Key 2</dt>
    <dd>Value 2</dd>
    <dt>Key 3</dt>
    <dd>Value 3</dd>
</dl>

<dl>
    <dt>Key 4</dt>
    <dd>Value 4</dd>
    <dt>Key 5</dt>
    <dd>Value 5</dd>
    <dt>Key 6</dt>
    <dd>Value 6</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: *Please do not use W3Schools as a reference*, please see **[W3Fools](http://w3fools.com)** for a long list of reasons why. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/dl) is one of several far superior HTML/CSS/Javascript references.

Comment: Was just the first hit on Google, but I'll give that W3Fools a read. Thanks!

Comment: If you're signed-in to Google, you can [block sites from appearing in search results](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1210386). This is especially useful in keeping w3schools out of your results `:)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can make the CSS work, then a `<dl>` would be the way to go for key-value association, as per the HTML5 spec:

- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-dl-element.html#the-dl-element

However, you *can* express the key-value association with a table, by using [the `headers` attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/attributes-common-to-td-and-th-elements.html#attr-tdth-headers):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th id="kv1_k">Key 1</th>
        <td headers="kv1_k">Val 1</td>

        <th id="kv4_k">Key 4</th>
        <td headers="kv4_k">Val 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th id="kv2_k">Key 2</th>
        <td headers="kv2_k">Val 2</td>

        <th id="kv5_k">Key 5</th>
        <td headers="kv5_k">Val 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th id="kv3_k">Key 3</th>
        <td headers="kv3_k">Val 3</td>

        <th id="kv6_k">Key 6</th>
        <td headers="kv6_k">Val 6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, given that the semantics of the data are expressed as well as possible, I don’t see anything wrong with using a table here.

Answer (score 1):

I would us a dl for this:

```
<div class="table">
  <dl>
    <dt>Key1</dt>
    <dd>Value1</dd>
    <dt>Key2</dt>
    <dd>Value2</dd>
    <dt>Key3</dt>
    <dd>Value3</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt>Key4</dt>
    <dd>Value4</dd>
    <dt>Key5</dt>
    <dd>Value5</dd>
    <dt>Key6</dt>
    <dd>Value6</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Then you can float and clear things accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A `<table />` has semantic meaning but your table content doesn't. It doesn't make sense on a non-visual level. There are no headers, no header scope.

There is some acceptance over using `<table />`s for layout apparently (trying to determine if it is presentational based on the whether a summary is included) but this is sketchy at best.

Really you should decide how you want to write your html for your users. You might be happy to use `<tables />` for this, just as someone might be happy to only use `<div />`s for all their mark up. On a visual level it *can* work. Just because it is easier to use tables for layout doesn't mean it is better or more sensible.

Less mark up can also be worse mark up.

I notice that you raise a concern about page zooming. I agree that this can be a pain to deal with, but I tend to expect the users who zoom pages to be, primarily, those with some form of sight difficulties. I think it would be remiss to focus on these people to the detriment of those users who have to use a screen reader to get at the content. There are ways around page zooming issues that don't require tables.

As a few people have said this is a great place to use a `<dl />` as it is semantically meaningful. The `<ul />` approach you show is, unfortunately, not as you are splitting up the value pairs.

Hopefully that makes some sense - happy to talk about specific points if you'd like. For myself meaningful mark up is always the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Semantic meaning - screen readers read lists as lists, no matter how convoluted the layout.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, tables do have their advantages, and shouldn't be completely disregarded in web development.

However, in most cases the flexibility of using a non-table CSS layout benefits the overall design of your web page.

Comment: Can you expand on this?  What kind of flexibility do you mean?  E.g. how do tables make it less flexible?  Mostly, I see tables presented the same... everywhere (which seems pretty flexible to me).  Whereas complicated CSS sites that try to mimic table-like presentation often need multiple stylesheets and rules even on a per browser basis to make sure things do not break.